# Is it not a right way to call my obj function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which is return a object. in the object i have two function to show the popup and close it. it works within the parent function, but it's not from out side.. is it not a right way to call that.. else how can i call the obj function from out side?

my function :

```
var popupHandler = function(handler,msg,popUp){

    msg =  msg == "help" ? "help" : "results"
    $(handler).click(function(){
        popObj.showPop(); //works
    })
    $('.cls-how2play').click(function(){
        if(msg == 'help') popObj.closePop(); //works
    });

    var popObj = {
        showPop  : function(){
                    if(!(popUp).is(':visible')) $(popUp).fadeIn().children().find('.'+msg).show().siblings().hide();
                },
        closePop : function(){
                    $(popUp).fadeOut()
                }
    }
    return popObj;
}
```

from calling ouside like this :

```
 $('.ui-footer').click( function(){ 
  var closeIt = popupHandler(); 
  closeIt.popObj.closePop() }) //not works.. why?
}
```

any one can help me the right way to call the obj functions from outside of the returning function?

thanks.

Comment: `closeIt` is already a reference to `popObj` as far as I can see, because of `return popObj;`.

Comment: `msg = msg === 'help' || 'results' ;`

Comment: @roXon: `msg === 'help'` returns `true` though. So you end up with `msg` either being `true` or `'results'`.

Comment: @Felix right. thanks for a tip to a tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are returning the `popObj`, your `closeId` will get only the two functions, not wrapped in the `popObj` object. Therefor you will call the function like so, without `popObj`:

```
closeIt.closePop();
```

Comment: even i added the code what you suggest, it calls that method. and the object not fading out.. why? any good reason..

Comment: @3gwebtrain My guess is that since you call popupHandler without passing any arguments `var closeIt = popupHandler();` your `popUp` variable will be `undefined` when you pass it as you selector `$(popUp).fadeOut()`.

Comment: is there the only way to pass the parameter from the method or anything else to fadeout?

Comment: @3gwebtrain Well, your popupHandler can take three arguments, as you have declared it now and popUp is one of them, so the easiest way to declare popUp would be to pass it when you create closeId `var closeIt = popupHandler("#somehandlerid", "help", "#yourpopupselector")`.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than

```
closeIt.popObj.closePop()
```

You want

```
closeIt.closePop()
```

Your `popupHandler` function *returns* the `popObj` object, which has the `showPop` and `closePop` functions on it. So `closeIt` is a reference to that same object.

Answer (score 1):

You should just call:

```
closeIt.closePop();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to wrap this in an object since you immediately return it.

you can write

```
return{
showPop  : function(){
                    if(!(popUp).is(':visible')) $(popUp).fadeIn().children().find('.'+msg).show().siblings().hide();
                },
        closePop : function(){
                    $(popUp).fadeOut()
                }
}
```

Now `closeIt.closePop();` should work very well.

Answer (score 1):

As i can c

popupHandler is a function, and popObj is a return result of the function "popupHandler"

when the program run to

```
var closeIt = popupHandler();
```

it means that the "closeIt" assigned by the result of the function "popupHandler", a obj as the same as the "popObj".

you can consider that "closeIt" is a copy of "popObj".

and "popObj" is not a property of "closeIt" , them are the same.

so you should code closeIt.closePop(), but not closeIt.popObj.closePop(),

and not popObj.closePop() as well.

because popObj was "var"ed in the declare of the popupHandler, it belonged that scope.